# Is there a difference between storing enumerations as integers versus strings?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Should I bother to store options like title, gender, and salutation as integers, or is it not relevant and I can store them as strings?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enumerize :gender, in: [:male, :female]

  TITLE = { dr: 0, prof: 1, prof_dr: 2 }
  def title
    TITLE.key(read_attribute(:title))
  end

  def title=(t)
    write_attribute(:title, TITLE[t.to_sym])
  end
end
```

Let's say I have 2000 users and 6 possible options for each of them.

Comment: Integers are generally better for performance, but strings are easier to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past when storage space was costly there were reasons to store strings as numbers. In this day and age except for embedded applications (which should probably not be running rails) there is not a need, especially given your example database size of 2000 users.

Also, if you store your strings as a number you will have the following downsides:

- Increased code complexity
- Database that can't be "read" without the code (Having done some database ports and written rails as a front end for back end data analysis these both become important.)

For performance concerns make sure you have your database keys setup correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Integers work better on the database level but make sure you remember what each of the numbers stand for.

Strings are much easier to work with because humans remember words better than numbers which is why we use URL's instead of IP's.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, integers have a performance benefit. Whether it's enough to matter is another question.

I would suggest doing whatever feels natural to you in writing code and developing an API. This will make your code intuitive to yourself (and others if applicable) and make you more productive in development.